If a known non Muslim in our city come to Masjid, are Muslims required to ask whether he converted to Islam or not?
Or can they just ignore him as long as he is doing what Muslims are doing in Masjid ?
What if he do not mind responding to question whether he converted or not? Can Muslims allow him to pray ?

Salaam,
In my opinion, absolutely not. If a non-Muslim visits a mosque, you want them to feel as comfortable as possible...not drive them away. :) Instead of worrying about asking if they are a convert or not, maybe ask them..."Is this your first time coming to this mosque?" This can help drive conversation, and maybe he/she will open up to you. :) Hope that helps, and may Allah (swt) help us welcome NonMuslims into our community in the most beautiful way possible.
-Muslim Gap

Wa'laikumussalam. Please read https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer . It is necessary that you provide references for your answers from reputable academic sources (Fatawa, quran, hadith, etc.). This site is not for personal opinions no matter how sensible and well-researched they are.
